# How to read Json on relative path in Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, kotlin

how do I access and read this Json 'someJson.json' that is in the repository but outside the Android modules? I need to access the json of a class without the context of activity, maybe there would be some way to access using the address reference?

And I can't move it to the Android Assets folder.

[image: project folders]

Answer (score 0):

assets folder is the place you need to put your external resources as while packaging an apk there is no relative paths meachism or any gradle like process which would help track your file and parse it, you need to use context there is no way of avoiding it,

Below link has a good implementation of assets json reading
https://bezkoder.com/java-android-read-json-file-assets-gson/